# How does Perl store integers in-memory?

Tags: perl

```
say pack "A*", "asdf";           # Prints "asdf"
say pack "s", 0x41 * 256 + 0x42; # Prints "BA" (0x41 = 'A', 0x42 = 'B')
```

The first line makes sense: you're taking an ASCII encoded string, packing it into a string as an ASCII string. In the second line, the packed form is "\x42\x41" because of the little endian-ness of short integers on my machine.

However, I can't shake the feeling that somehow, I should be able to treat the packed string from the second line as a number, since that's how (I assume) Perl stores numbers, as little-endian sequence of bytes. Is there a way to do so without unpacking it? I'm trying to get the correct mental model for the thing that pack() returns.

For instance, in C, I can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c[2];
    short * x = c;
    c[0] = 0x42;
    c[1] = 0x41;

    printf("%d\n", *x); // Prints 16706 == 0x41 * 256 + 0x42
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program makes incorrect assumptions about memory alignment restrictions (or rather, it assumes a lack thereof). Your program will crash on some machines. See my answer for the correct way to do the unpacking in C

Comment: Your program makes incorrect assumptions about the size of `short`. you should be using `int16_t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) as a serialization function.  It takes as input Perl values, and outputs a serialized form.  The fact the output serialized form happens to be a Perl bytestring is more of an implementation detail than a core functionality.

As such, all you're really expected to do with the resulting string is feed it to unpack, though the serialized form is convenient to have it move around processes, hosts, planets.

If you're interested in serializing it to a number instead, consider using [`vec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html):

```
say vec "BA", 0, 16;  # prints 16961
```

To take a closer look at the string's internal representation, take a look at [Devel::Peek](http://perldoc.perl.org/Devel/Peek.html), though you're not going to see anything surprising with a pure ASCII string.

```
use Devel::Peek;
Dump "BA";

SV = PV(0xb42f80) at 0xb56300
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0xb60cc0 "BA"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
```

Comment: If the fact that pack() returns a string is an implementation detail, how safe is it to print() that string?  Should I use syswrite() instead?  Are there any flags I should be passing to open() besides running binmode()?

Comment: It's a detail in the sense "it's got to be something Perl can manage, so a bytestring is what makes the most sense". AFAICT, as a bytestring it's safe to print to STDOUT no matter the binmode, though it would probably be a bad idea to mix it up with data that does rely on the encoding. You can safely `syswrite` it, but that's not a necessity.

Comment: Might not be safe on Windows because `\r` gets added before `\n` if it is a text file.

Comment: I'd argue that's more of a `say` problem than a `pack` one, though :-)

Comment: @JB., No `print` (and `syswrite`, which there's no reason to use here) would have the same problem.

Comment: Oh, I realize your point now. I haven't used DOS/Windows seriously in some time now, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4):

If you're really interested in how Perl stores data internally, I'd recommend [PerlGuts Illustrated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.46/index.html). But usually, you don't have to care about stuff like that because Perl doesn't give you access to such low-level details. These internals are only important if you're writing XS extensions in C.

If you want to "cast" a two-byte string to a C `short`, you can use the `unpack` function like this:

```
$ perl -le 'print unpack("s", "BA")'
16706
```

Answer (score 3):

> However, I can't shake the feeling that somehow, I should be able to treat the packed string from the second line as a number,

You need to unpack it first.

- To be able to use it as a number in C, you need

  ```
  char* packed = "\x42\x41";
  int16_t int16;
  memcpy(&int16, packed, sizeof(int16_t));
  ```
- To be able to use it as a number in Perl, you need

  ```
  my $packed = "\x42\x41";
  my $num = unpack('s', $packed);
  ```

  which is basically

  ```
  use Inline C => <<'__EOI__';

     SV* unpack_s(SV* sv) {
        STRLEN len;
        char* buf;
        int16_t int16;

        SvGETMAGIC(sv);
        buf = SvPVbyte(sv, len);
        if (len != sizeof(int16_t))
           croak("usage");

        Copy(buf, &int16, 1, int16_t);
        return newSViv(int16);
     }

  __EOI__

  my $packed = "\x42\x41";
  my $num = unpack_s($packed);
  ```

> since that's how (I assume) perl stores numbers, as little-endian sequence of bytes.

Perl stores numbers in one of following three fields of a scalar:

- `IV`, a signed integer of size `perl -V:ivsize` (in bytes).
- `UV`, an unsigned integer of size `perl -V:uvsize` (in bytes). (ivsize=uvsize)
- `NV`, a floating point numbers of size `perl -V:nvsize` (in bytes).

In all case, native endianness is used.

> I'm trying to get the correct mental model for the thing that pack() returns.

`pack` is used to construct "binary data" for interfacing with external APIs.

Comment: Updated/Added to my answer.